# hide multiple cells heightForRowAtIndexPath static tableview swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, heightforrowatindexpath

I want to change height of multiple static tableview cells to zero & back to normal.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if reminderHidden && indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

I can update bool value & above method works well for hiding one static cell. But it stops after returning one value. I would like to hide two static cells & bring them back to normal as I change one bool value.

Comment: My original question was to hide 2 cells together & unhide 2 cells together. My followup question is how to hide 2 cells individually. Without disturbing hide/show settings of 1st cell I want to hide or show 2nd cell & vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 1 && toggle.on == false {
        return 0.0
    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        if toggle.on == false || pickerVisible == false {
            return 0.0
        }
        return 165.0
    }
    return 44.0
}
```

For more detailed information visit my blog:

http://blog.apoorvmote.com/how-to-show-and-hide-static-cells-with-uiswitch/

Comment: Please add the explanation from your blog here otherwise you answer won't hold any valuable information in case the link becomes invalid. You could though add crucial points to your answer while leaving the link with extended information.

Comment: Does not work for me. heightForRow atIndexPath is ignored for static cells.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is return 0.1 in that function. 0 is the default (44px).
However you are going to find that there are lots of small issues when doing this. Such as:

1. When cells are resized after a reload, they will be laid out wrong.
2. When cells are supposed to be hidden, you can sometimes see their content under the cells around them

I find the better solution is to put (if possible) the cells that will be hidden into groups. Then in the data source set the number of rows to 0 for that section when hidden. There are still issues with this approach, but not as many.